# python usgsm2m module how to specify bounding box in cli

Tags: python, command-line-interface

been trying to use usgsm2m module using CLI but get "is not a valid floating point value"

if I try the --location option for a single point it works

usgsm2m search --username ####### --password ####### --dataset landsat_tm_c2_l1 --bbox 30.32,78.03,31.5,79.0 --clouds 5  --start 2005-01-01 --end 2005-12-31 --output display_id

also tried, but no luck

usgsm2m search --username ####### --password ####### --dataset landsat_tm_c2_l1 --bbox (30.32,78.03,31.5,79.0) --clouds 5  --start 2005-01-01 --end 2005-12-31 --output display_id

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should have used spaces instead of commas

```
usgsm2m search --username ####### --password ####### --dataset landsat_tm_c2_l1 --bbox 30.32 78.03 31.5 79.0 --clouds 5 --start 2005-01-01 --end 2005-12-31 --output display_id
```